# formatter->asDate - локализация (YII2)

Tags: yii2

Прописал в функции для вывода даты:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->date)
```

но как локализовать на русский?
Пробовал и так в функции указать:

```
public function getDate(){
      $locale = Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'ru-RU';
        return Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->date,[format($locale)]);
    }
```

Не срабатывает.
Получилось только в web изменить сам формат:

```
'formatter' => [
        'dateFormat' => 'd.MM.Y',
],
```

Comment: Что значит "Не срабатывает"? Какой результат ожидаете? Какой получаете?

Comment: Ранее было что-то наподобии такого формата: February 15, 2017
, а мне нужно, к примеру, 15 Янв 2017

Comment: Артём, расширение **intl** установлено?

Comment: В php.ini строчка разкомментирована: extension=php_intl.dll

Comment: Тогда выясни версию **ICU**.

Comment: Где я могу узнать версию ICU? в phpinfo() не нашел там информации. В php.ini тоже. Использую OpenServer.

Comment: Погуглите, как узнать. Я сейчас не вспомню. В сети точно есть информация. Если ICU старый, то лучше его обновить – из-за этого часто бывают проблемы с локализацией строк через intl.

Comment: Версия ICU: 57.1

Comment: Это достаточно новая версия... В этом случае затрудняюсь что-либо ещё советовать.

Answer (score 0):

Решение этого вопроса:
идем в web.php и в 'components' прописываем

```
'local' => 'ru',
```